# Слайдер на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Делаю слайдер на чистом JS и возникла проблема с перемещением. Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку слайда один раз, то слайд меняется плавно. Но в случаи когда пользователь нажимает несколько, слайды друг на друга наезжают. Есть ли возможность проверять через JS остававшийся количество времени до конца анимации, или как можно пофиксить это?

```js
 class Slider {
            /**
             * 
             * @param {array} arr 
             * @param {string} leftButton 
             * @param {string} rightButton 
             * @param {string} active 
             * @param {string} leftClass
             * 
             */
            constructor(arr, leftButton, rightButton, active, leftClass) {
                this.arr = arr;
                this.leftButton = document.querySelector(`.${leftButton}`);
                this.rightButton = document.querySelector(`.${rightButton}`);
                this.active = active;
                this.left = leftClass;
            }
            initialization() {
                this.rightButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.moveRight()
                });
            }
            moveRight() {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
                    if (this.arr[i].classList.contains(this.active)) {
                        this.leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
                        this.arr[i].classList.remove(this.active);
                        this.arr[i].classList.toggle(this.left)
                        this.arr[i + 1].classList.toggle(this.active);
                        if (i + 2 === this.arr.length) {
                            this.rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let arrSlide = [document.querySelector(".service__page1"), document.querySelector(".service__page2"), document.querySelector(".service__page3"), document.querySelector(".service__page4"), document.querySelector(".service__page5")]
        let slider = new Slider(arrSlide, "left", "right", "service__active", "service__left");
        slider.initialization();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
        
        .service {
            background-color: white;
            width: 700px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .service__page1 {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page2 {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page3 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: green;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page4 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page5 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__active {
            transform: translate(0);
        }
        
        .service__left {
            transform: translate(-120%);
        }
        
        input {
            padding: 10px 40px;
            margin-left: 150px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .service__page {
            opacity: 20%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="service">
        <div class="service__page1 service__page service__active">

            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__page2 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
        <div class="service__page3 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
        <div class="service__page4 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
        <div class="service__page5 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" disabled value="left" class="left">
    <input type="button" value="right" class="right">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: можно после клика делать setTimeout на время анимации

Comment: А еще есть событие `transitionEnd`.

Comment: @GGO Пробовал, но кода у 2 раза больше получиться. Добавлял флаг и тд и появлялся новый баг такого же типа, некоторые страницы плавно уходили но некоторые пролетали так же.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Как можно реализовать через это событие? В догадках только через флаг

Comment: Ну да, через флаг. Флаг сбрасывать при `transitionEnd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос был решен через добавления события "transitionend" в инициализацию.

```js
 class Slider {
            /**
             * 
             * @param {array} arr 
             * @param {string} leftButton 
             * @param {string} rightButton 
             * @param {string} active 
             * @param {string} leftClass
             * 
             */
            constructor(arr, leftButton, rightButton, active, leftClass) {
                this.arr = arr;
                this.leftButton = document.querySelector(`.${leftButton}`);
                this.rightButton = document.querySelector(`.${rightButton}`);
                this.active = active;
                this.left = leftClass;
            }
            initialization() {
                this.rightButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    this.moveRight()
                });
                this.arr.forEach((el) => {
                    el.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
                    this.flag = false;
                    })
                })
            }
            moveRight() {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
                    if (this.arr[i].classList.contains(this.active)&& !this.flag) {
                        this.flag = true;
                        this.leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
                        this.arr[i].classList.remove(this.active);
                        this.arr[i].classList.toggle(this.left)
                        this.arr[i + 1].classList.toggle(this.active);
                        if (i + 2 === this.arr.length) {
                            this.rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let arrSlide = [document.querySelector(".service__page1"), document.querySelector(".service__page2"), document.querySelector(".service__page3"), document.querySelector(".service__page4"), document.querySelector(".service__page5")]
        let slider = new Slider(arrSlide, "left", "right", "service__active", "service__left");
        slider.initialization();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
        
        .service {
            background-color: white;
            width: 700px;
            height: 500px;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .service__page1 {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: blue;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page2 {
            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page3 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: green;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page4 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__page5 {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            transform: translate(120%);
            transition: 1.5s;
        }
        
        .service__active {
            transform: translate(0);
        }
        
        .service__left {
            transform: translate(-120%);
        }
        
        input {
            padding: 10px 40px;
            margin-left: 150px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        
        .service__page {
            opacity: 20%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="service">
        <div class="service__page1 service__page service__active">

            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="service__page2 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
        <div class="service__page3 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
        <div class="service__page4 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
        <div class="service__page5 service__page">
            <div></div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="button" disabled value="left" class="left">
    <input type="button" value="right" class="right">


</body>

</html>
```